# Binding data from mysql to wpf application

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf

I fetch the data from a database using [mysqlconnector](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-introduction.html) by filling DataSet :

```
DataSet myData = new DataSet();
MySqlDataAdapter adapter;

string query = "Select * from visitors";
string table = "visitors";
adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(query, connection);

adapter.Fill(myData, table);
```

I tried to bind the data from `myData` to DataGrid (`MainWindow.xaml.cs`) :

```
    var data = myData.Tables["visitors"].AsEnumerable();
    dataGrid.ItemsSource =  data;
```

and `MainWindow.xaml`:

```
`<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True">
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="First name" />
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Second name" />
</DataGrid.Columns>
<DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <DockPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=firstName, TargetNullValue=no data}"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=secondName,TargetNullValue=no data}"/>
        </DockPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
</DataGrid>`
```

and the only thing that I get is 23 blank rows - the same number as in mysql table. I googled this problem but I cannot find the appropriate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I will give you a theoretical solution.

1. Create an Observable Collection (example: `ObservableCollection<Person>`) wherein `Person` has the property like `firstName` and `secondName` as you mentioned in your code.
2. Fill the `ObservableCollection` with the `Dataset` which you retrieve form the `Database`.
3. At last `Bind` the `ObservableCollection` to the `ItemSource` of the `DataGrid`.

In your above code snippet you are not `Binding` the `ItemSource`, you have just mentioned the `Properties`.

`<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Path = PersonCollection}">`

Comment: Thanks, it worked. However, specyfing ItemsSource in DataGrid `ItemsSource="{Binding Path = PersonCollection}"` doesn't work.Instead I'm setting `dataGrid.ItemsSource = personCollection;` in `MainWindow.xaml.cs` and then `                            <DataGrid.Columns>
                                <DataGridTextColumn Header="firstName" Binding="{Binding Path=LastName}" />
                                <DataGridTextColumn Header="lastName" Binding="{Binding Path=FirstName}" />
                            </DataGrid.Columns>` inside `MainWindow.xaml`.